# How to show an iframe pop-up on top of parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe that acts as page footer. This iframe shows a pop up (the iframe has a button and it contains the pop up) but when I use it on the page the pop-up gets behind the containing div.

How can I show part of the pop up in the parent.

[image: want / have]

**Updated**

Now with some code :

iframe has a pop up:

https://codepen.io/oscarryz/pen/MNdjGm

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="footer">
    <button id="showpopup">Show popup</button>
    <div id="infobox" class="hidden">PopUp</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And content uses that iframe as pop up

https://codepen.io/oscarryz/pen/rXgvNM

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="content">Content</div>
  <div class="footer">
    <iframe src="https://codepen.io/oscarryz/full/MNdjGm" style='border:0;width:100%;height:500px;overflow:hidden' frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is basically the same code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57436857/20654) but using a div as pop up inside the iframe

Comment: iframe contains the pop up?

Comment: *behind the containing div.*  --> I guess it get truncated inside the iframe because you cannot have things outside of it

Comment: @epascarello yes.

Comment: Question updated with working code

Answer (score 1):

The keyword here is stacking context.
Look at this minified example of your question, which should work as expected:

(please run the snippets in full page mode)

```js
document.getElementById('showpopup').addEventListener('click',function() {
  document.getElementById('infobox').classList.remove('hidden');
});
```

```css
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
}
.page {
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
height: 80%;
width: 100%;
background: #eee;
}
.footer {
height: 20%;
width: 100%;
background: #444;
}
#showpopup {
margin: 3em;
}
#infobox {
height: 200px;
width: 80%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 15%;
left: 10%;
}
.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
 <div class="content">Page Content</div>
 <div class="footer">
  <button id="showpopup">Show iframe</button>
 </div>
 <iframe id="infobox" class="hidden" src="https://bing.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Now, the difference to the page you have is either, that your page uses z-index for the main content, or absolute positioning of other elements and the iframe. If the iframe has a lower z-index or is added to the document before other absolutely positioned element, it will get hidden behind it:

```js
document.getElementById('showpopup').addEventListener('click',function() {
  document.getElementById('infobox').classList.remove('hidden');
});
```

```css
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
}
.page {
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
height: 80%;
width: 100%;
background: #eee;
z-index: 99; // PROBLEM CAUSE A
position: absolute; // PROBLEM CAUSE B
}
.footer {
height: 20%;
width: 100%;
background: #444;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}
#showpopup {
margin: 3em;
}
#infobox {
height: 200px;
width: 80%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 15%;
left: 10%;
}
.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
 <div class="footer">
  <button id="showpopup">Show iframe</button>
 </div>
 <iframe id="infobox" class="hidden" src="https://bing.com"></iframe>
 <div class="content">Page Content</div>
</div>
```

To solve this, you either need to move your iframe down in the document, or give it a higher z-index itself.

Comment: ah yeap, but the problem is the whole footer is the iframe and it has the pop up inside 

`<iframe><div class="popup"></iframe>`

Comment: Sorry I misunderstoof your question then. Please provide some code though and let us know if the iframe is under your administration as well or if it's external. Some code of the frame itself would be helpful to figure out why it is cut off in the first place and not just adding a scrollbar for example.